# Wix installer always install my service under Local System Account

Tags: wix

I am creating wix installer for windows service.
But my windows service is not getting installed under the service account which I pass instead it always installed under Local System Account. Please help.

```
  <Component Id="MySImporterService" Guid="{3EA5076C-C3FA-4A5F-95A5-365C6919DEB4}" KeyPath="yes">
      <ServiceInstall Id="MyInstall"
                   Type="ownProcess"
                   Name="MyService"
                   DisplayName="MyService"
                   Start="auto"
                   Account="[SERVICE.USERNAME]"
                   Password="[SERVICE.PASSWORD]"
                   ErrorControl="normal" />
      <ServiceControl Id="MyControl"
               Stop="both"
               Remove="uninstall"
               Name="MyService"
               Wait="no"/>
    </Component>
```

Comment: Have you ensured that `[TA.SERVICE.USERNAME]` is filled at the time this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

It seems clear that (as Cole suggests) the values for SERVICE.USERNAME and SERVICE.PASSWORD are not correct. Those identifiers are Windows Installer properties that need to resolve to valid accounts at install time. A verbose log will show if they are getting set correctly.

Another issue may be that the install might get a repair, and that will result in re-install of the service so those properties would need to be available at that time as well as at install time.

Edit: Make sure that the property names are marked Secure=Yes in your WiX, otherwise they won't get preserved properly into the Execute sequence.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for the response.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for the response. I checked the values for SERVICE.USERNAME and SERVICE.PASSWORD are correct still wix intaller doesn't setting username and password. FYI - I am using Tohshelf framework to create this windows service.

Comment: Please find some part of logs below. Here action  MigrateFeatureStates and RemoveFiles retuns 0 and all other actions retuns 1. 

=== Logging started: 15/04/2014  16:00:32 ===
Action start 16:00:32: INSTALL.
Action start 16:00:32: FindRelatedProducts.
Action ended 16:00:32: FindRelatedProducts. Return value 1.
-
-
-
Action start 16:00:32: MigrateFeatureStates.
Action ended 16:00:32: MigrateFeatureStates. Return value 0.
-
-
-
Action start 16:00:33: RemoveFiles.
Action ended 16:00:33: RemoveFiles. Return value 0.
-
-
-
-
Action ended 16:00:35: INSTALL. Return value 1.